# react event target parent node

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

Is it possible to get the event target's parent node on the virtual DOM?

In my basic react component I have a method which is triggered from onClick event, I would like to get the parent virtual DOM node properties.

```
handleClick(e){ 
    // The following code only gives me the actual DOM parent Node
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(e.target).parentNode 

}
```

Comment: Maybe post more of your code and why you need to to do this, as there might be a better way.

Comment: The click event triggers a modal, which it's content populated determine by what reference has been passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. React works on a virtual DOM model, and will update the real Browser DOM only if needed. The events in React work on a virtual DOM also and they are called [synthetic](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) events. If you find that you need the underlying browser level event for some reason, simply use the nativeEvent attribute to get [it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

There are some constraints in React Virtual DOM that you may read from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html):

Also, [this](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/the-difference-between-virtual-dom-and-dom/) may be helpful and explains the difference between the Virtual Dom and Browser DOM.

---

Browser DOM is just an abstraction of the on page elements, and React DOM would be an abstraction of that abstraction.

The `render` method of `ReactDOM` is crucial how we send React elements to Browser DOM:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var root = React.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(root, document.getElementById('example'));
        ^ 
        |---- Where React elements from React Virtual DOM enter the Browser DOM
```

In React we are dealing with React Elements and React Components.

[image]

Since React Element is a virtual representation of a DOM Element, to work with the events and catch the parents, you need to create React Components either of these three ways:

[image]

To navigate the parent inside the click Event for instance you may check this:

```
 var parent = this._reactInternalInstance._currentElement._owner._instance;
```

REF: [is there any way to access the parent component instance in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257665/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-parent-component-instance-in-react) and http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/j8uaq85e/