# react-native with styled-components parent prop

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm working with styled-components on my react-native project and I wonder how can I get the parent prop from a child element .. here is an example, I've 2 styled-components

```
const First = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: ${props => props.selected ? 'blue' : 'red'};
`
const Second = styled.Text`
  // here I want to check if First has the selected prop.
  color: ${props => props.selected ? '#fff' : '#000'};
`
```

and my own React component

```
const Test = () = (
  <First selected>
    <Second>Test</Second>
  </First>
)
```

now how can I check if `Seconds` father (which is `First`) has the `selected` prop ?
I know it will work if i'll give the selected attr to `Second` but it's not what I'm trying to achieve ... there must be a way because they nested, I tried to console log and props arg but I couldn't find the parent value in the object that the child returns.

thanks

Comment: Pass the parent props as new props to child..

Comment: @John, thats the point that I dont want to use the same prop twice, I want to get it from the parent

Comment: You are getting it from parent itself when you pass as props to child. This is the simplest way. However it is not recommended to access parent instance in child. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257785/1066839

Comment: @John, thanks that's exactly what I looked for, I was kinda sure there is a 'helper' or something from `styled-components` that would help in these kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow React's pattern, there is one way. To pass the same prop to the `<second>`.

what you can do though, is to use an appropriate prop to the child like the following

```
const Test = () = (
  <First selected>
    <Second isParentSelected={selected} >Test</Second>
  </First>
)
```

and then

```
const Second = styled.Text`
  color: ${props => props.isParentSelected ? '#fff' : '#000'};
`
```

Comment: the point was as I said in the post that I don't want to repeat the props in every component, I just wanted the childrens to use the father's prop.
thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need this behaviour you can style the child inside the parents as follows, however Matthew's answer is the preferred way:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Second = styled.Text`...`;
const First = styled.View`
    display: flex;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: ${props => props.selected ? 'blue' : 'red'};

    ${Second} {
        color: ${props => props.selected ? '#fff' : '#000'};
    }
`
```

Alternatively you can wrap all the new styles in block with the `css` function:

```
import styled, {css} from "styled-components";

const Second = styled.Text`
    color: #000
`;

const First = styled.View`
    display: flex;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;

    ${props => props.selected && css`
        background-color: blue;
        ${Second} {
            color: #fff;
        }
    `}
`
```