# How to access child's props from parent's styled-component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

I have kind of this construction:

```
  <Wrapper activeTextColor="red">
    <Text active={true}>Text 1</Text>
    <Text active={false}>Text 2</Text>
  </Wrapper>
```

Styled-components should look like this:

```
const Text = styled.p``;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  ${Text} {
    ${props =>
      props.activeTextColor &&
      css`
        /* How to make color red based on "active" attribute of Text element? */
      `}
  }
`;
```

How to access child's props from parent's styled-component here?

Here is a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-water-gmxj7)

Comment: you wouldn't do that right? You would make a real component that housed this styled component and use that to pass the correct props to the children

Comment: @CallumLinington hit the nail on the head. I'm not even sure what you're trying to do is doable as it goes completely against the point of styled components (since that component is no longer just a component).

Comment: something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-cloud-8dtwj ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (as far as I can tell). But you can access the parent's props from the child component (the other way around). That seems to accomplish what you are trying to do.

**Short answer:**

*You have to pass the parent prop to the child component*.

In a parent component `<Wrapper />` you would have to clone your children and pass the `activeTextColor` to the children:

```
const StyledWrapper = styled.div``;

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children, activeTextColor } = this.props;
    return (
     <StyledWrapper activeTextColor={activeTextColor}>
       {React.Children.map(children, child =>
         React.cloneElement(child, {
           activeTextColor: activeTextColor
         })
       )}
     </StyledWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Both `activeTextColor` and `active` are now accessible from the `Text` component.

```
const Text = styled.p`
  ${props => css`
    color: ${props.active ? activeTextColor : "#000"};
  `}
`;
```

**Another Option:**

In the case above, it might make more sense to go with a ThemeProvider/ThemeConsumer. If you know an `activeTextColor` is going to be red (maybe you are dealing with design tokens), then access the active colors with:

```
${props => css`
  background: ${props.active ? props.theme.activeTextColor : '#000'};
`}
```

**Detailed Answer** (*and why someone would want to do this*):

This extends the Short Answer above. At some point you might need to access the parent props in the parent component, and both the child and parent props in the child component.

A real world example would be something like Tabs. I have two different styles / variants of Tabs, with both the `Tabs` container component and `Tab` needing its own styles depending its own props. It is one component styled two different ways.

### [image: Tab Example]

Nesting the styled-components won't work. So you end up with something like this.

```
const StyledTabs = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  ${props =>
    props.variant === "wizard" &&
    css`
      justify-content: space-between;
    `}
`;

const StyledTab = styled.p`
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  ${props => css`
    background: ${props.active ? "#fff" : "#f6f6f6"};
  `}

  ${props =>
    props.variant === "box" &&
    css`
      & {
        border-right: 0 none;
        &:last-child {
          border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        border-top: ${props.active
          ? "2px solid lightseagreen"
          : "1px solid #ddd"};
        border-bottom: ${props.active ? "none" : "1px solid #ddd"};
      }
    `}

  ${props =>
    props.variant === "wizard" &&
    css`
      & {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        color: ${props.active ? "#fff" : "#000"};
        ${props.active && "background: lightseagreen"};
      }
    `}
`;

class Tabs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children, variant } = this.props;
    return (
      <StyledTabs variant={variant}>
        {React.Children.map(children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(child, {
            variant: variant
          })
        )}
      </StyledTabs>
    );
  }
}

class Tab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children, variant, active } = this.props;
    return (
      <StyledTab variant={variant} active={active}>
        {children}
      </StyledTab>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Tabs variant="box">
      <Tab active={true}>Tab 1</Tab>
      <Tab>Tab 2</Tab>
      <Tab>Tab 3</Tab>
    </Tabs>
    <Tabs variant="wizard">
      <Tab active={true}>Step 1</Tab>
      <Tab>Step 2</Tab>
      <Tab>Step 3</Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Full example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-thunder-wfo2m

Related issue on styled-component's GitHub:
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1193

There are quite a few related questions on StackOverflow, but I don't think there are many clear answers:
[react-native with styled-components parent prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401488/react-native-with-styled-components-parent-prop)
[How to style a child component from a parent styled component, considering passed props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769277/how-to-style-a-child-component-from-a-parent-styled-component-considering-passe)

Comment: Seems to be the most relevant answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
const Text = styled.p`color: ${props => props.active ? "red" : "palevioletred"};`;
```

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if you edited it to explain why it is correct and why it is the best answer for the question, so that others can learn from your knowledge.