# Styled-components, how to refer to a child component and still use the childs props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to allow `Cells` in my table have a specific background based on whether or not the parent `Wrapper` has the `prop.printMode` provided.

Here is a simplified breakdown:

```
<Wrapper printMode>
  <Table>
    <Row key={index}>
      <Cell severity='Low'>x</Cell>
      <Cell transparent>y</Cell>
      <Cell>z</Cell>
    </Row>
  </Table>
</Wrapper>;
```

simplified `Cell`

```
interface ICell {
  transparent?: boolean;
  alignLeft?: boolean;
  severity?: unknown;
}

export const Cell = styled('div')<ICell>`
  background-color: ${(props) => 
   (props.transparent === true ? 
    'transparent' :
    props.theme._palette.main.tiles[100])};

  ${(props) =>
    props.alignLeft &&
    css`
      display: flex;
      align-content: flex-start;
      padding-left: 0.5rem;
    `}

  ${({ severity }) => {
    if (severity === 'High') {
      return css`
        background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme._palette.colors.red[0]};
        color: ${({ theme }) => theme._palette.colors.red[60]};
      `;
    }
    if (severity === 'Low') {
      return css`
        background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme._palette.colors.blue[0]};
        color: ${({ theme }) => theme._palette.colors.blue[60]};
      `;
    }
  }}
`;
```

simplified `Wrapper`

```
export const Wrapper = styled('div')<{ printMode?: boolean }>`
  min-width: 750px;
  max-width: 1000px;

  ${({ printMode }) =>
    printMode === true &&
    css`
      ${Header} {
        background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme._palette.colors.red[80]};
      }
      // I want to access / handle the props for ${Cell}, but I lose access to them
      // something like the following would be ideal:
      //
      //   ${Cell} {
      //     background-color: ${(props) => transparent === true ?
      //      'transparent' : 
      //      props.theme._palette.colors.red[80];
      //   };
      //
    `}
`;
```

screenshot of above example shows that it is looking at the styled-component `theme` object and not the component level props passed in `Cell`.

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can get approach to handle the Children prop styles concisely within `Wrapper` when `Wrapper.printMode` is passed? In the `Wrapper` example directly above, `transparent` is effectively always false.

Comment: You can pass the `printMode` to `Cell` components also.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Using the current pattern shown above? Or passing `printMode` directly to each cell? -- If so, I'm trying to avoid that, I'd prefer to avoid having to funnel logic directly into every `<Cell />` within the table. Makes the code a bit messy. If I can handle it in entirely in the `Wrapper` that would be pretty succinct.

Comment: It does, but unfortunately, you can't access the child's props within the parent.

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803505/how-to-access-childs-props-from-parents-styled-component

Comment: dang that's too bad ... Thank you for the link + feedback

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with classes (or some other selector), though this would mean employing a different strategy which may not be desirable.

Something like:

```
<Wrapper printMode>
  <Table>
    <Row key={index}>
      <Cell severity='Low'>x</Cell>
      <Cell className='_transparent'>y</Cell>
      <Cell>z</Cell>
    </Row>
  </Table>
</Wrapper>;

export const Wrapper = styled('div')<{ printMode?: boolean }>`
  min-width: 750px;
  max-width: 1000px;

  ${({ printMode }) =>
    printMode === true &&
    css`
      ${Header} {
        background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme._palette.colors.red[80]};
      }
      // I want to access / handle the props for ${Cell}, but I lose access to them
      // something like the following would be ideal:
      //
      //   ${Cell} {
             background-color: ${props => 
              props.theme.palette.colors.red[80]};

             &._transparent {
              background-color: 'transparent';
             }
      //   };
      //
    `}
`;
```