# Access React component underlying DOM tree

Tags: reactjs

I have a form validation that recurses through all children on submission, checks if child is one of my custom "form field" components (Input(), Checkbox(), SelectBox()), etc, checks the components' values against some validation rules, and clones the component with an "invalid" prop if the value is invalid. Validation works fine and invalid "form field" components display styles for invalid fields. After the form is submitted the validation happens inline.

If the form is invalid, I would like to scroll the page to the first invalid element after form is submitted but unfortunately components do not expose the underlying DOM three (except via the Fiber object) and I cannot get the "ref" of any component.

I read through all documentation and through React issues that relate to this topic and apparently it is not possible to access a component's DOM tree (unless through ref forwarding, which I am trying to avoid because I would like the Form to handle all validation related code).

This question is my last try: is there a native way in React to access a component's DOM tree from a parent component without using ref forwarding?

**UPDATE**
I am getting the ref when I clone the component:

```
updateField = (field, validationRule) => 
  React.cloneElement(field, {
       invalid: true,
       validationMessage: validationRule.message(field.props),
       ref: node => node && this.invalidFields.push(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node))
  });
```

Comment: You can expose the child dom to parent by doing ref forwarding..

Comment: Thanks Arup. Yes, I could but I would have to implement ref forwarding on every form field component, which I am trying to avoid. I am trying to encapsulate all validation related functionality within the Form itself.

Comment: In that case, need to once the components flows.. how they are connected. :)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean :/

Comment: *I could but I would have to implement ref forwarding on every form field component, which I am trying to avoid. I am trying to encapsulate all validation related functionality within the Form itself.* - how do these two things contradict each other? You will forward refs and use them in parent component, right?

Comment: There is no contradiction. It is just a design choice. I want to handle all validation related functionality on the form itself without having to change my components' implementation. I can get the component ref when I clone the invalid field (see update on the queston).

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257665/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-parent-component-instance-in-react) perphaps this helps

Comment: Fiber is an ongoing change in React's core algorithm. It is not part of the public API and it should not be accessed by external code:

https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture
https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/288