# React: Enforcing a child component under specific parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a components like this:

```
<Dialog id="_login" modal={true} onSubmit={() => console.log("x")} onCancel={() => console.log("C")} visible={true} >
    <DialogHead>
        Title Here
    </DialogHead>
    <DialogBody>
        <Field id="username" label="User Name" onChange={(id, value) => { console.log(id, value) }} />
        <Field id="password" label="Password" onChange={(id, value) => { console.log(id, value) }} />
    </DialogBody>
    <DialogFoot>
        <button onClick={e => console.log(e)}>Close</button>
    </DialogFoot>
</Dialog>
```

This below is `<Dialog>` render code

```
public render() {
    return <div className="hx-dialog-outer" onClick={this.onCancel.bind(this)}>
        <div className="hx-dialog-inner" onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}>
            <form name={this.props.id}>
                {this.props.children}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

How do I force a child element under parent element? I mean, `<DialogHead>`, `<DialogBody>` and `<DialogFoot>` should not valid outside `<Dialog>` container. For example, if it being used like this below, it will produce an error like "ERROR: DialogHead must be nested in Dialog Component"

```
<div>
    <DialogHead>
        Title Here
    </DialogHead>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the concept of **Containment**, where **Dialog** component would be:

```
function Dialog (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and now you can use this:

```
<Dialog id="_login" modal={true} onSubmit={() => console.log("x")} onCancel={() => console.log("C")} visible={true} >
    <DialogHead>
        Title Here
    </DialogHead>
    <DialogBody>
        <Field id="username" label="User Name" onChange={(id, value) => { console.log(id, value) }} />
        <Field id="password" label="Password" onChange={(id, value) => { console.log(id, value) }} />
    </DialogBody>
    <DialogFoot>
        <button onClick={e => console.log(e)}>Close</button>
    </DialogFoot>
</Dialog>
```

This is the reference: [Containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: The OP means "how can I make it so DialogHead throws an error when used outside of a Dialog container"

Comment: Oh ok, well, the child component in this case DialogHead  can detect his parent through this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257665/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-parent-component-instance-in-react) and the idea would be that child can detect his parent and if is not his parent throw an error

Comment: I have checked that SO thread about `_reactInternalInstance`, but it is said not to use for production? It is kind of hacking internal React working.

Answer (score 1):

[React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) might be what you want.

```
// Parent <Dialog/>
class Dialog extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    dialog: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      dialog: this.props.dialog
    }
  }
}

// Children <DialogHeader/>, <DialogBody/>, <DialogFooter/>
const DialogHeader = (props, context) {
  if (context.dialog == null)
    throw new Error('You should not use <DialogHeader/> outside a <Dialog/>')
  // return some markup
}

DialogHeader.contextTypes = {
  dialog: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

w/ new context API since React 16.3+

```
const {Provider: DialogProvider, Consumer: DialogConsumer} = React.createContext(null)

const Dialog = props =>
  <DialogProvider value={{dialog: props.dialog}}>
    {props.children}
  </DialogProvider>

const DialogHeader = props =>
  <DialogConsumer>
    {({ dialog }) => 
      if (dialog == null) return new Error()
      // return some markup
    }
  </DialogConsumer>
```

Comment: How do I generate an error if it being used independently? Since `<DialogHead>`, `<DialogBody>`, and `<DialogFoot>` has some props that should be used within `<Dialog>` component.

Comment: Personally, I feel that using context for this is a bit of a hack; however I do think that this is the nicest solution for now....