# Is possible to force a component to be used inside another component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to create 2 react components `<Father />` and `<Child />` and force the developer to use `Child` only inside `Father`:

```html
<Father>
    <!-- should be fine -->
    <Child />
</Father>

<!-- should throw an error -->
<Child />
```

Is there any way to do it? If so, what's the syntax I should use?

Comment: If you are rather trying to create a pattern for developer you should take a look into `Context` and `Provider`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240796/react-enforcing-a-child-component-under-specific-parent

Comment: I don't think that solves the issue OP is having @shota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the `context API` to determine whether a child has a `Father` in parent or not.

The way you can do that is for your Father component to render a `ContextProvider` and your child to use the context

```
const FatherContext = React.createContext(null); // default value used if father not in hierarchy

const Father = ({children}) => {
   // Component Logic here
   return (
       <FatherContext.Provider value={"Father"}>
        {/* rest content */
        {children}
       </FatherContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

and your Child can be like

```
const Child = () => {
   const context = useContext(FatherContext);
   if(context == null) {
       console.warn("Child must be rendered inside of Father component"); // You can throw an error here too
   }

   return (...)
}
```

Now depending on which version of React you use, the implementation of Context differs but the idea remains the same

Comment: Using context like this would be a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something out of the box like this:

```
<Father>
  {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props, dna: 'uniquefather'})}
</Father>
```

```
Child class
...
if (this.props.dna !== 'uniquefather') throw new Error('something');
```

Here, the father will be passing an unique identifier, which if not received will throw error in child class.

Comment: In this case what will stop the developer to use `<Child dna="uniquefather"/>` outside of every `Father`?